# update requires a IOS later than before

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, version

I have a app in store that requires iOS 3.0 or later. I want to add some features that need iOS 3.2 or later. What happen with users that already have the app installed? Will they be able to update? I hope not... because if they do it will crash.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a perfectly valid question, and relates to programming environments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

Set the iOS Deployment Target in the targets build settings to iOS 3.2 . Users who are using iOS 3.0 wouldn't be able to install the updated app because you set the min OS version to be 3.2. Updated app won't show in updates section of App Store for those users running iOS <= 3.0 others would see this as update available.

Comment: thanks. Is there some statistics related to how many users over the world still use iOS 3.2 earlier?

Comment: I don't know answer for that. You can integrate some analytics into your app and get stats about your app. I would guess very less % are still using iOS 3.0 and its not worth your time and effort to support iOS 3.0 users and this is my personal opinion not based on any stats.